# Use of a deprecated module 'string'

Tags: python, string

I just ran `pylint` on my code and it shows up this message:

`Uses of a deprecated module 'string'`

I am using the module `string` for join / split mainly.

```
>>> names = ['Pulp', 'Fiction']
>>> import string
>>> fullname = string.join(names)
>>> print fullname
Pulp Fiction
```

Above is an example. In my code I have to make use of `split` and `join` a lot and for that I was using the `string` module.

Has this been deprecated? If yes, what is the way to handle split/ join in Python 2.6? I have tried searching but I could not find myself being clear so I asked here.

Comment: What tutorial or book gave you the notion that you should use string.join etc and not methods of the str class?

Comment: @John: http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch09.html

Comment: This is shocking and astonishing. It purports to be version 2 and has Copyright 2010 on each page. Chapter 7 is about strings and it mentions only the string module, despite string methods having been introduced in Python 2.0 in October 2000, almost TEN years ago. I suggest that you stop reading it instantly.

Comment: @John: Advice taken and accepted, I was not referring to these tutorials now, but I read them sometime back and somehow the wrong way of doing stuck with me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Equivalent to your code would be:

```
' '.join(names)
```

`string` is not deprecated, deprecated are certain functions that were duplicates of `str` methods. For `split` you could also use:

```
>>> 'Pulp Fiction'.split()
['Pulp', 'Fiction']
```

In docs there is a [full list of deprecated functions with suggested replacements](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions).

Answer (score 1):

not all functions from "strings" are deprecated.
if you want to use a function from strings which is not deprecated, then remove a string from deprecated-modules configuration in pylint config.

```
[IMPORTS]
deprecated-modules=string
```

Comment: .pylintrc says this: “; Deprecated modules which should not be used, separated by a comma”. So, according to you, that's misleading or too much imperative.

Answer (score 0):

I used to call `split`, `join` and `strip` as methods of string objects until one day I needed to make a script more efficient.

Profiling using `cProfile` showed me that a lot of time was spent on these method calls. [Performance tips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...) suggested me to instead make a "copy" of these methods in my scope to avoid this:

```
split = str.split
join = str.join
for _ in xrange(1000000):
    print join("_", split("Pulp Fiction"))
```

If I remember well, the trick indeed resulted in performance gains.

However, if I need these string manipulation functions in several functions, I make these copies in the "global scope" of my program (not sure this is the correct way to say it). `pylint` then complains that I'm not using the correct convention for naming my variables:

```
Invalid name "split" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
```

So I end up naming them with capital letters:

```
SPLIT = str.split
JOIN = str.join

def main():
    for _ in xrange(1000000):
        print JOIN("_", SPLIT("Pulp Fiction"))
```

It's a bit ugly, though.

Sometimes I forget about the possibility to make copies and do imports:

```
from string import split, join
```

And then I get the `Uses of a deprecated module 'string'` warning.